# To show $\int_{a}^{a+T} f(x)dx$ is independant in $a$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, periodic-functions

It is said that $f(x+T) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in domain of $fx$ then we have to show $\int_{a}^{a+T} f(x)dx$ is independent in $a$.

My method says that let $F(a) = \int_{a}^{a+T} f(x)dx$ then 
$$F'(a) = f(a+T)-f(a) + \int_{a}^{a+T} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} f(x ) dx = 0$$

so it means $F(a)$ is independent in $a$. This proof is not very good?? Give good proof please. thank.

Miss said dont try derivative as it can be non differentiable, use property of integration.
I also try $x-a = u$ to get $\int_{0}^{T} f(u+a) du$ but what to do now. Thank.

Comment: somebody answer it i have exams, i will flunk

Comment: Differentiate your integral with respect to $a$ to get $f(a+T) - f(a) =0$ and hence the integral is constant and independent of $a$.

Comment: Yes that what I do teacher said - no wrong. She said - try some properties of integration, your proof is not good.

Comment: Your proof is wrong. You should just get $F'(a) =f(a+T) - f(a)=0$. You have an extra $\int\frac{\partial} {\partial a} $ thing. This is not needed.

Comment: Paramnandad - she also gave drawing of function like $\sin x$ from $\pi/3$ to $2\pi + \pi/3$ so it becomes obvious, but its not proof

Comment: No drawing is needed. Wait I will write a complete answer.

Comment: Paramnandad - I use feynman tricks

Comment: Why not to substitute $x+a$ in $f$? This will give you $\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{T}f(x+a)dx =  \int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx $

Comment: shcol - I tried this!! but couldnot get end results

Comment: So you got for $\forall a$ the $\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx =  \int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx $, which is not depend on $a$

Comment: No no i got $\int_{a}^{a+T}f(x)dx =  \int_{0}^{T}f(x+a)dx$ !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$F(a) =\int_{a} ^{a+T} f(x) \, dx\tag{1}$$ and via Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have $$F'(a) =f(a+T) - f(a) =0$$ therefore $F(a) $ is independent of $a$. You don't need to give any more explanation.

---

The above can be proved without differentiation also. We have $$F(a) =\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\,dx+\int_{T} ^{a+T} f(x) \, dx-\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$ and in the second integral put $t=x-T$ to get $$F(a) =\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{a}f(t+T)\,dt-\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$ Since $f(t+T) =f(t) $ second and third integral are equal and cancel each other so $$F(a) =\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\,dx$$ which is independent of $a$.

Comment: I use feynman tricks, is it not good

Comment: Paramnandad - teacher says dont use differentiation, its may not be differentiable o

Comment: @KingTut : you may have a look at the updated answer. Perhaps your teacher wants this kind of proof.